# Maven configeration error - (JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory)

Tags: java, maven

I have installed  apache- maven in windows, and set the environmental variables :

```
M2_HOME - C:\Users\bg4730\apache-maven-3.3.9;
M2 - %M2_HOME%\bin;
JAVA_HOME - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_74;
```

Even though I am getting (JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory) when I am trying to check the maven installation from command line: mvn --version

Comment: Is the `;` really there? Try to remove it from `JAVA_HOME`.

Comment: What exactly does `echo %JAVA_HOME%` output?

Comment: I think you need " around the path when it contains spaces.

Comment: Once you created `JAVA_HOME` variable add `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` in  `PATH` variable.

Comment: create a new variable called **path** and `path=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%M2_HOME%\bin;`

Comment: Refer https://maven.apache.org/install.html

Comment: Thanks, I removed the semicolon  from JAVA_HOME

Answer (score 2):

If this is the actual value...

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_74;
```

The semicolon at the end should be the culprit. What happens is it gets executed like this on Windows: `%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java` so if the semicolon is there, it's going to be part of the path that gets executed.